# Pi 3B+ (several of them ! ) no longer perfortm USB boot

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, boot-issues

All 5 of my 3B+ no longer perform a USB boot, from USB stick. Problem first noticed where OS was MoodeAudio and a HiBerry Hat was in use. Other similar systems (using diferent 3B+'s with different DACs and/or amp hats have the same problem By experimenting with different OS, including Moode, Buster and Bullseye Raspbian/Pi OS on these three Pis, plus two others which have no Hats, I tracked it down to USB boot not working.

USB sticks have included old and new, and will boot a 4B+ satisfactorily.
There are no other devices attached, except USB  dongle that supports mouse and keyboard.
Power supply is official Pi micro-usb (although I have also used official Pi USB-C.

I'm stumped.

Comment: What do you observe on the display when the issue occurs? you say "no longer", which implies it worked at some stage, what changed, e.g. an update? does "vanilla" Raspberry Pi OS with no hat boot from USB?

Comment: Do they boot if you remove the hats?